# How to delete camelLock files

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus, delete-file

We are running Apache-Camel in a Quarkus environment, and we would like to delete the files ending with **camelLock**, as soon as the process has finished. We just do some processing on "pdf" files. So, no copying to an endpoint.
What do we have to change on the code below so that the lock files (xxx.yyy.camelLock) are deleted after processing ?

```
  from(
       file(input).antInclude("*.pdf").readLock("changed"))
       .routeId("signaturcheck")
       .throttle(8).timePeriodMillis(1000)
       .process(checkPdfSignature)
        // log message
       .log("File handled ${file:name}")
       .to("stub:null");
```